# Serve first static page if exists

Tags: django, apache, nginx

I have the following scenario; I have a simple blog application which takes entries from a DB. Standard CRUDL, nothing special.

Since a blog article/page is more read than modified, I would like to generate a static page first time a blog page is served and serve that for subsequent queries.

My only solution is to write a view decorator to check for a static page and serve that if exists (and generate it if it doesn't). Is it possible to configure apache (or nginx) to do the conditional serving part?

Yes, I know that I could use a static blog generator, but my aim is to extend the applciation beyond just a simple blog.

Comment: have you considered caching the pages instead? if your fear is the db lookups, you can just use django cache middleware and it'll cache the responses tied to the urls.

Comment: @toad013 : yes, that would be the default solution. However, if the cache expires or the server goes down, the generation would happen again and that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Nginx documention](http://nginx.org/en/docs/) states it's possible using the [try_files](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) directive to try a local file and then fall back to a proxy (Gunicorn running your Django app for example).

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri.html @django;
}

location @django {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000; 
}
```

Looks like there is a way to achieve the same functionality in Apache. See the following question and answer for an explanation: https://serverfault.com/questions/290784/what-is-apaches-equivalent-of-nginxs-try-files.

Using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ balancer://app_cluster%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Cool stuff. Is there an equivalent in Apache?

Comment: I've added a link to an Apache solution. Could you please accept my answer if you're happy with it. Thanks